# How to fill shapes with line pattern in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, drawing, diagram

I can draw the outlines and add Latex variables in Inkscape, but how does one fill those objects with line patterns as in the below diagrams? Also how to cut out the pattern to fill text(or latex symbols) as in the 2nd diagram?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can [choose a pattern as a fill](https://imgur.com/yFjdAyy). This is fairly basic stuff TBH. It might be worth your while having a look at some beginner tutorials for Inkscape. There are lots on youtube.

Comment: i have used it but it draws very thick lines which i don't want. can you post links to those tutorials so that i can know how it is done, 'cause I'm unable to find any, probably i's searching with wrong keywords

Comment: You can adjust the scale of the pattern by moving the pattern controls. Move the one with the square handle closer to the X. The circle controls rotation.  You can also create your own custom patterns.  To find tutorials on youtube, search for "beginner Inkscape tutorials". Or specifically look for a channel called "Logos by Nick". It's pretty good.